# Unable to connect to repository over VPN

Tags: git, git-extensions

A colleague in another continent is unable to connect to our Git repository.  He is connected on the company's virtual private network (VPN).  He is attempting to access the Git repository using Git Extensions.

When he attempts to configure a remote (Remotes > Manage remote repsitories) and test the connection he gets the error

> FATAL ERROR: Network error:Connection timed out

If he just tries to `pull` from remote the "window just sits there...nothing happening even after leaving it for 15 mins"

**Other relevant info:** The network location of the Git repository is mapped to a Windows drive letter.  He is able to access this drive using Windows Explorer.

Any workaround or hint on what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Can he ping the repository host?

Comment: @roryWoods  Repository is just a networked directory and he can access it using Windows Explorer with no problem.

Comment: Is the host acting as the remote repo running git? Are you connecting with ssh, http?

Comment: It isn't "running" anything.  It is just a networked location that is a bare Git repository.  It is accessed as a Windows path --> `X:\project-repo`.

Comment: Can he write to the folder via the share?

Comment: I haven't asked...I don't believe he's tried that.  No reason to doubt he can.  I will check.  I will also ask him to try with a wired connection (versus WiFi).  I am told of instances where Git has issues with packet loss.  Another thing he will try is other clients (EGit and TortoiseGit) to see if it is a GitExtensions issue or ...  Thanks for offering suggestions.

Comment: Sorry couldn't help. I had this URL tucked away in my git on windows stash. http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2011/08/20/simple-guide-to-running-git-server-on-windows-in-local-network-kind-of.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see if he is able to set up a remote from the command line like your reference suggests.

Comment: @SriSankaran, Any solution u found for this problem? I having same issue now.

Comment: @Suganthan I can't recall.  That was a different time, different job :-P.  Try the tip suggested by roryWoods (see comment of Dec 2 '11 at 21:26)